# Java Regex Exclude a Pattern ?! Usage

Tags: java, regex

I understand that ?! is to exclude a pattern,  so for example a(?!b) means it will match "a" if "a" is not followed by "b".
My question is, suppose I have a file with the following content:

```
a cat is a cat, a dog is a dog,

a bird is a bird.
```

How many times will the pattern a(?!.*b) match?  Is it 0 times? since all "a"s are before the "b" in the last word "bird"?

Comment: I don't know much regex but this site is godly: https://regex101.com/

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/sI4wE1/1 . You could play with the regex in this site.

Comment: This site is awesome! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will match for every `a`. The pattern `a(?!b)` means it will match any `a` not **immediately** followed by `b`. `cab` wouldn't match, but `a bird` will.

**EDIT**

With your new pattern `a(?!.*b)`, no match if all of your text is on the same line. The `.*` does not match linebreaks, so:

> A cat is a cat, a dog is a dog
>
> A bird is a bird

This would have matches for every a of the first line.

Comment: No problem, I will edit my answer, but your assumption is right; no match except linebreaks. See above

Comment: .* matches any character (except newline). I didn't know * couldn't match linebreaks. Hence the confusion. :D   Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: * can, `.` can't ;) If you want to check everything, including newlines/linebreaks, I believe you would use `[.\s]*`. My pleasure! Have fun with regexes :)

Comment: @Docteur, `[.\s]` matches a literal dot or a whitespace character.  If you want to match any character *including newlines*, use the dot in Singleline/DOTALL mode.  One way to do that is with an inline modifier: `(?s)a(?!.*b)`

Comment: Whoops, you are right. However, would [\s\S] be possible too? Thank you @AlanMoore

Comment: Yeah, that works, too.  That idiom comes from JavaScript and other ECMAScript implementations, which don't have a dot-matches-everything mode, but it works in all regex flavors.